# Selenium not submitting login fields

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

EDIT: Updated with page URL

I am trying to login to a website through Selenium (python) but the driver is not filling in the login and password fields nor is it submitting the page. The browser opens to the correct website but then nothing else happens even though I fill in my fields and click the login button. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located

def document_initialised(driver):
   return driver.execute_script("return initialised")


os.environ["LANG"] = "en_US.UTF-8"
# Using Chrome to access web
driver = webdriver.Chrome('my path to webdriver')
# Open the website
driver.get('https://members.crunchfitness.ca/members/sign_in')

WebDriverWait(driver).until(document_initialised)

# Select the id box
user_box = driver.find_element_by_name('member[email]')
user_box.clear()
user_box.send_keys('my username')

pass_box = driver.find_element_by_name('member[password]')
pass_box.clear()
pass_box.send_keys('my password')

# Find login button
login_button = driver.find_element_by_name('commit')
# Click login
login_button.click()
```

Comment: can you provide page url or page source?might there iframe?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to enter username and password and also able to click on login button and nothing happening means click event on login button not performed properly.
If this is the case then use ActionChains class mechanism or by javascript click on the login button.